# NSXML Parsing - Distinguishing Nodes

Tags: iphone, xml, cocoa-touch, nsxmlparser, nsxml

I am trying to extract the doc-num from the following xml using NSXML.  At this point I am able to iterate through all the nodes using the NSXML parser event, but I am trying to distinguish between the doc-num in the input node from the one in the output node.

How can I do this?  I am a bit lost on how to get this to work for my iphone app. Also, is there a simpler way than the event based NSXML?

```
     <xmt:input>
        <xmt:app-refer>
            <doc-id doc-id-type="docdb">
                <country>MD</country>
                <doc-num>20050130</doc-num>
                <kc>A</kc>
                <date>20050130</date>
            </doc-id>
        </xmt:app-refer>
    </xmt:input>
    <xmt:output>
        <xmt:app-refer>
            <doc-id doc-id-type="epodoc">
                <doc-num>MD20050000130</doc-num>
                <date>20050130</date>
            </doc-id>
        </xmt:app-refer>
    </xmt:output>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a tutorial that shows XML parsing using GDataXMLParser.

[how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml](http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml)

GDataXMLParser is better than NSXMLParser since latter is slower.

Comment: Excellent! Let me take a look.

Comment: And yes, I believe this will do the trick! Thank you very much.